# Name Image and create Container with Python Docker SDK

Tags: python, docker, sdk

I currently have the need to create an image from a Dockerfile with the Python Docker SDK, and then run a container based on that image.  I know how to run a container based on an image I manually create, however, when I try to use the Python Docker SDK to create the image, I can't figure out how to pass a name to the image, which I can then reference when I run a container based on the image.  Looking at the docs [here](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/images.html) I don't see a parameter for name.

When I do create the image, based on the Dockerfile, using the SDK, it creates an unnamed image, however has an ID.

```
import docker

def main():
    folder_path = './node-sample'
    client = docker.from_env()

    try:
        image = client.images.build(path=folder_path)
        print image
    except RuntimeError as e:
        print e

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is the image it creates, it doesn't have a name: `<Image: ''>`

It has an ID, though: `1e3bc3e1eb43`

The Dockerfile I have is super-simple, right now:

```
FROM node:6.14.2
EXPOSE 8080
COPY server.js .
CMD node server.js
```

I'd like to be able to create an image, with a name I choose, and then run a container based on that image using the Python Docker SDK.

Answer (score 1):

From doc [here](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/images.html), you can build an docker image and tag its using "tag" 
parameter.

> tag (str) – A tag to add to the final image

```
client.images.build(path="./", tag={image_tag})
```

this code above actually like you are typing `docker build -t {image_tag} .` command in the docker cli.

then, using the specific image tag to run the docker container.

```
client.containers.run({image_tag}, name={container_name}, detach=True)
```

Answer (score -1):

I was able to pull out the ID from the image, and then pass that in when creating the container.

```
import docker
import re

def main():
    folder_path = './node-sample'
    client = docker.from_env()

    try:
        image = client.images.build(path=folder_path)[0]
        image_id = re.sub(r'(sha256:)', '', image.short_id)
        client.containers.run(image_id, detach=True, ports={'8080/tcp': 8080})
    except RuntimeError as e:
        print e

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```